# What is the Chemical Compound that has a NFPA 704 (Fire Diamond) of 2-2-1-ox?

Tags: safety, reactivity, toxicity

I recently saw this fire diamond configuration of:

2 - Flammability;
2 - Health;
1 - Reactivity;
OX - Extra Information

I have been attempting to find a database of terms, but after turning up with nothing, and seeing a similar answer about [fire diamonds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NFPA_704) answered here, I posted this question.

I would be thankful if someone happened to know what compound that this fire diamond is labeled to.

Comment: Unless it's something incredibly common, I feel like there are too many possibilities. There are only so many possible combinations for the safety diamond, and well over an Avogadro's number of possible compounds that could exist.

Answer (score 2):

From what I found NIOSH lists 6 compounds with 2-2-1 pattern, but none of them are labeled with oxidizing properties:

- ethylhexaldehyde: [NFPA 704 2-2-1](https://www.cdc.gov/niosh/ipcsneng/neng0621.html);
- benzyl chloride: [NFPA 704 2-2-1](https://www.cdc.gov/niosh/ipcsneng/neng0016.html);
- 2-methyl-1-butanol: [NFPA 704 2-2-1](https://www.cdc.gov/niosh/ipcsneng/neng0506.html);
- n-octyl mercaptan: [NFPA 704 2-2-1](https://www.cdc.gov/niosh/ipcsneng/neng1493.html);
- vinyl toluene: [NFPA 704 2-2-1](https://www.cdc.gov/niosh/ipcsneng/neng0514.html);
- methyl chloroacetate: [NFPA 704 2-2-1](https://www.cdc.gov/niosh/ipcsneng/neng1410.html).

On the other hand, there are oxidizers with slightly different NFPA diamond which much as well be the candidates:

- ammonium dichromate [NFPA 704 2-1-1-OX](https://www.cdc.gov/niosh/ipcsneng/neng1368.html);
- amyl nitrate [NFPA 704 2-2-0-OX](https://cameochemicals.noaa.gov/chemical/2477).

The values might deviate a little in different sources and they also depend on conditioning.