Looking to identify potential chemicals with NFPA 704 rating 1-2-3-OX
As the title suggests, I'm trying to find a good method to locate potential chemicals with a fire diamond of 1-2-3-OX.
The sign was on a single large tank, so I assume it was a single substance within (I also believe it was a gas).
I've tried Cameo Chemicals and OSHA but haven't had any luck yet.
Thank you!

And this tank was where, that is, on what kind of premises?

A hydropower plant, not near any type of machinery that I could discern the purpose from.

Hmmm… https://www.newenv.com/resources/nfpa-chemicals/ has none with 1-2-3 oddly enough.

@JonCuster I appreciate the help! Maybe I'll have to find literature on the specific compound instead of trying to search a database.

Related posts: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/85342/what-is-the-chemical-compound-that-has-a-nfpa-704-fire-diamond-of-2-2-1-ox?rq=1 ... https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/172657/is-there-any-chemical-that-has-a-fire-diamond-nfpa-704-of-3-4-2-cor-oxy?noredirect=1&lq=1
